# How to enable docker containers ping each other via their host names?

Tags: docker, networking, ping, hostname, docker-network

I'd like to be able to ping a docker hostname from another docker container. how can i do that ?
My containers are on the same docker network.

Can someone guide me where should I look or search, I'm very newbie in networking and do not know about what should i search to fix this problem.

Comment: Look at the `--link` option if you are using `docker run` or the `links` section in docker-compose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `link` option is deprecated so I suggest you to use the `--network-alias` option in addition to the `--name` flag (see the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/) for more info).

For example, admiting you have a network called test, you can run these two commands (in two separate terminal)

```
docker run -it --rm --name debian1 --network=test --network-alias=debian1 debian:jessie /bin/bash
docker run -it --rm --name debian2 --network=test --network-alias=debian2 debian:jessie /bin/bash
```

Then you will be able to ping containers according to their network-alias

Comment: how is the network-laias different from docker hostname ? ( sorry if it's a stupid question )

Comment: thank you very much, that actually worked pretty well !!